# How to unpack contents of list in a class method in python?

Tags: python, class, attributes

I have a python class, and it has a method. I want to define attributes inside this method and I want to assign items of a list to this attributes, but it won't allow me to:

```
class ReaderThread(threading.Thread):       
    def __init__(self, telex_path, ac_types):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        self.message = [1,2,3]

    def calculate(self):
        self.message_type, self.new_date, self.old_code = self.message
```

It says:

```
AttributeError: 'ReaderThread' object has no attribute 'message_type'
```

Traceback:

```
Exception in thread Thread-1:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\lib\threading.py", line 810, in __bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "Q:\Users\myuser\workspace\new\scriptt.py", line 89, in run
    self.calculate()
  File "Q:\Users\myuser\workspace\new\scriptt.py", line 93, in calculate
    self.message_type, self.new_date, self.old_code,
AttributeError: 'ReaderThread' object has no attribute 'message_type'
```

What is wrong above?

Comment: No, I'm defining self.message_type inside calculate method.

Comment: Could you post the traceback?

Comment: Yea this code works fine for me. Python3...

Comment: Post the full code, looks like you forgot to call `calculate` on the instance.

Comment: The traceback does not match the code you've posted. I don't see a line `self.message_type, self.new_date, self.old_code,` in the `calculate` method in your posted code.

Comment: … and, unlike the line you showed us in your example code, the line that Hans Zauber points out from your traceback is trying to _access_ `self.message_type`, not _set_ it, which would cause exactly the error you're seeing. So, the code you posted is fine; we can't debug the different code you didn't post. See [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) for more on how to figure out what to post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is hard to describe exactly, because it doesn't actually appear in the code that you showed us. But I can guess at what your actual code looks at, and explain how to fix that guess.

---

The traceback says this:

```
  File "Q:\Users\myuser\workspace\new\scriptt.py", line 93, in calculate
    self.message_type, self.new_date, self.old_code,
AttributeError: 'ReaderThread' object has no attribute 'message_type'
```

But there is no such line in your code. The closest thing is this:

```
    self.message_type, self.new_date, self.old_code = self.message
```

That line is perfectly valid—it's attempting to *set* `message_type`.

The line you're getting an error about isn't trying to set it, it's only trying to *access* it. And since no such attribute yet exists, you get an `AttributeError`.

---

Almost certainly, in your *actual* code, you're doing something like this:

```
    self.message_type, self.new_date, self.old_code,
    self.other_attribute, self.fifth_attribute = self.message
```

That may look to you like a single statement, exactly the same as the example you showed us—but it's not. Python (unlike, say, C or JavaScript) has very strict rules about when a statement continues on to the next line, and in any other case, the end of the line is the end of the statement, period.

The first line is a complete statement on its own: a simple expression statement, where the expression is a tuple of three values. Just as you can write either `1, 2, 3` or `1, 2, 3,` on a line in the interactive interpreter and see `(1, 2, 3)`, you can write `self.message_type, self.new_date, self.old_code,` and it will evaluate to the tuple `(self.message_type, self.new_date, self.old_code)`. Normally, your code would be useless and misleading, but harmless; in this case, because you haven't actually created these attributes yet, you get an `AttributeError`.

The second line is of course a normal assignment statement that will unpack `self.message` into `self.other_attribute` and `self.fifth_attribute` (probably raising a `ValueError` for having too many elements to unpack, but you never get that far).

---

The simplest and most common rule for when an expression is continued on the next line is when there are unclosed parentheses, square brackets, or braces. And you can take advantage of that here, because what you're effectively doing is assigning to a tuple,* and tuples can always be written inside parentheses. So:

```
(self.message_type, self.new_date, self.old_code,
 self.other_attribute, self.fifth_attribute) = self.message
```

---

* I'm cheating a bit here in the explanation, because the thing on the left side of an assignment is not really an expression, and specifically not really a tuple, but an assignment *target list*. But the rules have been carefully designed to make sure that target list forms are a clear subset of expression forms. See [assignment statements](http://docs.python.org/3.3/reference/simple_stmts.html#assignment-statements) in the reference docs for the exact syntax.

Comment: Sir you were right, I had to put attributes inside parenthesis when defining them, because there were new lines between variables when defining them. thanks a lot.

Comment: @alwbtc: This is exactly why you want to paste an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). I happened to guess eventually, with a lot of help from Hans, what your code _probably_ looked like. But that took 45 minutes, one incorrect answer, dozens of comments, 3 downvotes to your question, and a lot of hassle for half a dozen people, including you. If you'd just shown us code that demonstrated the problem, someone would have given you an answer immediately.